# RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView, split binary file in chunks

Tags: javascript, parsing, stl, binary

i have simple threejs [viewer](https://jsfiddle.net/Simon060694/39jhczkp/) and it should work with big stl file size, so currently for files over 300mb the browser is crashing on parse the data from file, i was thinking to split data from file in chunks and parse this chuncks as different geometries, but catch error `RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView` can someone give an advise how to fix stl binary parser to get full model data for webgl context?